# Call function loaded with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am Loading  data to my div from a html,  like this:

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html');
```

Inside `test.html` I have an `alertme` function.
Is there a way to call this method after the html is loaded in the current document?

Comment: Just call it after it has finished (callback), script will be parsed like the rest of the HTML

Comment: please show how `alertme` is defined within `test.html`

Comment: @Alnitak, why is it relevant?

Comment: because for it to be callable it must be global.

Comment: @Alnitak, well... it is true even for inside `test.html` page, but you're right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html', function(){
    alertme();
});
```

- [An unworking example without the wrapping function](http://jsfiddle.net/KpNaw/)
- [A working example with the wrapping function](http://jsfiddle.net/KpNaw/1)